# cxf puts source files in target but compiler can't see them?

Tags: java, maven, cxf

I'm just starting out with cxf, so it's probably a newbie mistake..

I'm working through the book soa governance in action, and have downloaded the example project.

When I use cxf to build sources from a wsdl, it places the sources in the 'target' directory of eclipse. But these are java files it has created, and the compiler doesn't seem to see them, so building the application that requires these files fails with compiler errors.

Am I supposed to add the generated-sources directory in 'target' to the build path or something?

Many thanks!

EDIT: Thoroughly confused. Here's the pom

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        build-helper-maven-plugin
                                </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.7,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute></execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        cxf-codegen-plugin
                                </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <execute></execute>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>

                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>target/generated/cxf</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/contract/accountService.wsdl</wsdl>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.manning.ossoagov.chapter2</groupId>
        <artifactId>traffic-service-general</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

EDIT: I'm also not clear how I'm supposed to build it..? I am running it as a maven build in eclipse, with a goal of generate-sources. That seems to generate the sources. But how am I supposed to build the whole package? It doesn't compile even when the source has been generated..? Many thanks!

EDIT: Updated Maven logs

```
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.manning.ossoagov.chapter2:traffic-service-remoting-WS:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${cxf.version} @ line 134, column 15
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Traffic Service WS Remoting 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- cxf-codegen-plugin:2.3.2:wsdl2java (generate-sources) @ traffic-service-remoting-WS ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- build-helper-maven-plugin:1.7:add-source (add-source) @ traffic-service-remoting-WS ---
[INFO] Source directory: /Users/bw/Documents/workspace3/traffic-service-remoting-WS/target/generated/cxf added.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ traffic-service-remoting-WS ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 3 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ traffic-service-remoting-WS ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ traffic-service-remoting-WS ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!    [INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO]    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ traffic-service-remoting-WS ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7.1:test (default-test) @ traffic-service-remoting-WS ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /Users/bw/Documents/workspace3/traffic-service-remoting-WS/target/surefire-reports
```

---

```
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.1:jar (default-jar) @ traffic-service-remoting-WS ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/bw/Documents/workspace3/traffic-service-remoting-WS/target/traffic-service-remoting-WS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ traffic-service-remoting-WS ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/bw/Documents/workspace3/traffic-service-remoting-WS/target/traffic-service-remoting-WS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/bw/.m2/repository/org/manning/ossoagov/chapter2/traffic-service-remoting-WS/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/traffic-service-remoting-WS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/bw/Documents/workspace3/traffic-service-remoting-WS/pom.xml to /Users/bw/.m2/repository/org/manning/ossoagov/chapter2/traffic-service-remoting-WS/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/traffic-service-remoting-WS-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8.179s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Apr 16 07:49:17 BST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

EDIT: Trying to narrow it down. I have a 'Maven Problem' that "Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.3.2:wsdl2java failed. (org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.3.2:wsdl2java:generate-sources:generate-sources)"

But if I go to the command line and do 
    mvn org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:wsdl2java

then I get BUILD SUCCESS

Is it possible that the automatic build of eclipse is not running it in the same way or something? Could it be the warning..?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.manning.ossoagov.chapter2:traffic-service-remoting-WS:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar -> duplicate declaration of version ${cxf.version} @ line 134, column 15
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]                                                                     
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Traffic Service WS Remoting 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- cxf-codegen-plugin:2.3.2:wsdl2java (default-cli) @ traffic-service-remoting-WS ---
[INFO] Nothing to generate
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.868s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Apr 16 09:37:40 BST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Are you using eclipse Java EE edition?

Comment: I believe so. Why would that make a difference? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be adding this folder into classpath, Using maven you can do this like:

```
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-wsdl-source</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/path/to/generated/sources</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks - I think I have that in my pom (please see above).

Comment: Change the "phase" make it process-sources from generate-sources.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference? I changed the phase to process-sources and ran a maven build with a goal of process-sources, and it just created the source files like before in target, but doesn't compile them..

Comment: Are these complete logs I don't see the compiler plugin getting executed.

Comment: Updated the logs. First time I was just running the goal process-sources. This time I ran maven install. I still see errors in eclipse where the compiler can't see the generated source even though the build succeeds? Confused.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Things seem to be running in proper sequence, generate -> add -> compile, as per logs. Is wsdl located in proper location. Best way run maven in debug mode.  "mvn -X clean install"

Comment: Thanks - did mvn -X clean install. Build succeeds. That is what I don't get. How can I get eclipse to compile? Seems like the build is OK?

Comment: I need the updated logs to see what happened... This command just runs maven with detailed logging.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I just right clicked the folder  where the generated sources are kept and choose

```
Build Path -> "Use as source Folder "
```

Now eclipse will know where it is . Then all the errors went off .

Be careful while choosing the folder because doing it on wrong folder will give a wrong package name.
.